# How to install waf?

Tags: python, waf

I have cloned and built the `waf` script using:

```
./waf-light configure
```

Then to build my project (provided by [Gomspace](https://gomspace.com/home.aspx)) I need to add `waf` and the `eclipse.py` to my path. So far I haven't found better than this `setenv` script:

```
WAFROOT=~/git/waf/
export PYTHONPATH=$WAFROOT/waflib/extras/:$PYTHONPATH
export PATH=~/git/waf/:$PATH
```

Called with:

```
source setenv
```

This is somehow a pretty ugly solution. Is there a more elegant way to install waf?

Comment: Why not just use mod_security at your web server level?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fedora (at least Fedora 22) has a yum package for waf, so you could see that it's possible to do a system install of waf, albeit with a hack.

After you run something like `python3 ./waf-light configure build`, you'll get a file called `waf` that's actually a Python script with some binary data at the end. If you put it into `/usr/bin` and run it as non-root, you'll get an error because it fails to create a directory in /usr/bin. If you run it as root, you'll get the new directory and `/usr/bin/waf` runs normally.

Here's the trick that I learned from examining the `find_lib()` function in the waf Python script.

1. Copy the `waf` to `/usr/bin/waf`
2. As root, run `/usr/bin/waf`. Notice that it creates a directory. You'll see something like `/usr/bin/.waf-2.0.19-b2f63c807a4215294bf6005410c74c18`
3. mv that directory to /usr/lib, dropping the `.` in the directory name, e.g. `mv /usr/bin/.waf-2.0.19-b2f63c807a4215294bf6005410c74c18 /usr/lib/waf-2.0.19-b2f63c807a4215294bf6005410c74c18`
4. If you want to use waf with Python3, repeat Steps 2-3 running the Python script `/usr/bin/waf` under Python3. Under Python3, the directory names will start with `.waf3-`/`waf3-` instead instead of `.waf-`/`waf-`.
5. (Optional) Remove the binary data at the end of `/usr/bin/waf`.
6. Now, non-root should be able to just use `/usr/bin/waf`.

That said, here's something to consider, like what another answer said: I believe waf's author intended waf to be embedded in projects so that each project can use its own version of waf without fear that a project will fail to build when there are newer versions of waf. Thus, the one-global-version use case seems to be not officially supported.

Answer (score 5):

You don't install waf. The command you found correctly builds waf: `/waf-light configure build` Then for each project you create, you put the built `waf` script into that projects root directory. I can't find a reference, but this is the way in which waf:s primary author Thomas Nagy wants the tool to be used. Projects that repackage waf to make the tool installable aren't "officially sanctioned."

There are advantages and disadvantages with non-installation:

Disadvantages:

- You have to add the semi-binary 100kb large `waf` file to your repository.
- Because the file contains binary code, people can have legal objections to distributing it.

Advantages:

- It doesn't matter if new versions of waf break the old API.
- Users don't need to install waf before compiling the project -- having Python on the system is enough.